# A regular expression for checking the sigils of only one language

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like that the regular expression forbids the use of different languages;
It should only allow Russian or English. Together never!

For example: 
Яроslav

John Дое

My expression at the moment:

```
/^([a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ]+[,.]?[ ]?.*[a-zа-яёА-ЯЁ]|[a-zа-яёА-ЯЁ]+['-]?.*[a-zа-яёА-ЯЁ])+$/i
```

I suppose it will look like this:

```
^([a-zA-Z]|[а-я])+$
```

Comment: Then what do you want to allow ?

Comment: and how should it distinguish ukrainian and russian words?

Comment: It should only allow Russian or English. Together never!

Comment: Write two regex for English and Russian and test string separately.

Comment: Use an alternation with putting quantifier inside of each side `^(?:[\u0400-\u04FF]+|[a-zA-Z]+)$`

Comment: /^(?:[а-я]+|[a-zA-Z]+)$/i    it isn't working

Comment: What can there be inside the string apart from letters?

Comment: @NikitaKaydash: An idea: maybe it is enough for you to check if there are glued Enlgish and Russian letters, and if found, report a failure? Like `if (/[a-z][а-яё]|[а-яё][a-z]/i.test(str)) { console.log("Never together!"); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way using a regular expression is to work with characters range.

Assuming Russian characters range is `а-яё` and English characters range is `\u0041-\u007a` (both can be reduced or extended) you could use the following regular expression to check if a string contains only either Russian characters or English characters and not both (plus any whitespace character) :

`^[а-яё\s]+$|^[\u0041-\u007a\s]+$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k9t7xH/4)

**BUT** English characters are also used in a LOT of languages.

For example, in French *café* will be excluded but not *bonjour* which is not an english word.

Comment: `[\u0400-\u04FF]` matches [more than just Russian letters](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf), it matches all Cyrillic letters.

Comment: You're right Wiktor, it's a quick example. As latin languages except english cannot be excluded using a regex, I didn't go further.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew BTW, can you help me fix russian characters set ? I've used Wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet

Comment: Russian letter regex is `/[а-яё]/i`

Comment: Thank you, answer and demo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to fail any string that contains both an English and Russian letter. The `/[a-z][^а-яё]*[а-яё]|[а-яё][^a-z]*[a-z]/i` regex will do exactly that, so all you need to do is negate the `RegExp#test` result:

```js
var ss = ["Яроslav", "John Дое", "Good string", "Вот так строка, молодец!"];
var rx = /[a-z][^а-яё]*[а-яё]|[а-яё][^a-z]*[a-z]/i;
for (var s of ss) {
  console.log("Testing", s, ":", !rx.test(s));
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i6wUwX/1).

**Details**:

- `[a-z]` - an ASCII letter (note it will match uppercase letters due to the `/i` case insensitive modifier)
- `[^а-яё]*` - 0+ chars other than Russian letters
- `[а-яё]`  - a Russian letter
- `|` - or
- `[а-яё][^a-z]*[a-z]` - a Russian letters, followed with 0+ chars other than ASCII ones and then an ASCII letter.